# Nested eager loading with constraint not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am having hard time using nested with constraint. Can someone help me to group subjects based on the what semester it will be offered.

MyController

```
public function show($id)
{
    $student = Student::with(['course', 'course.curriculum', 'course.curriculum.subjects' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('sem_offered');
    }])->findOrFail($id);

    return view('students.show', compact('student'));
}
```

show.index

```
@foreach($student->course->curriculum->subjects['first first-sem'] as $subject)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $subject->subject_code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $subject->subject_description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $subject->units }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>98</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: First of all what's wrtong with it? You getting error or no results. I see two places that can breaks: first is this `['first first-sem']` key - is it ok. The secoud one is subject relation return a Collection (probably) so you should not call it like an array...

Comment: @shaddy Im getting undefined index 'first first-sem'. To clarify things, the first first-sem is a value of 'sem_offered. In my Curriculum and Subject I included withPivot('sem_offered').